# one query to display both promoted and non promoted links

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a page of links which will show all links sorted by live_date- the catch here is that there are two types of links - promoted and non promoted- the other catch is- the list should be grouped by day so todays links will returned the promoted links then the non promoted links- then yesterdays promoted and non promoted.

```
Fridays links

-------------
Promoted link
Promoted link
Promoted link
Normal link 
Normal link
```

```
Thursdays Links
--------------
Promoted link
Normal link 
Normal link 
Normal link
```

And so on-

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reciprocal_checkbox` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `recip` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `promoted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `live` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `live_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I was think something like this but i dont think it will create all the promoted links first then non promoted (which is defined by a bool)

```
SELECT title, link, live_time FROM links WHERE promoted = 1 UNION SELECT title, link, live_time FROM links WHERE promoted = 0 GROUP BY live_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to group, you just want to order them...

```
SELECT title, link, live_time 
FROM links 
ORDER BY live_date DESC, promoted DESC
```

PS - doesn't look like you have a `live_date` column.  Did you want something like this?

```
SELECT title, link, live_time 
FROM links 
ORDER BY DATE(live_time) DESC, promoted DESC
```

Comment: This is so simple compared to what i had in my head

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT title, link, live_time FROM links
ORDER BY live_date, promoted
```

Comment: Nope, he wants them ordered desc.

Comment: Fair enough, well spotted.